# NHibernate: Simplest way to return an object with paged children collection?

Tags: nhibernate, paging

I want to return one Parent object with the children collection eagerly loaded with the requested page (subset) of children objects.  What's the best way to achieve this?   Filters? Is is possible with an ICriteria query?

I'm using  .SetFirstResult() and .SetMaxResults() to do paging for collections of aggregate root results, but is it possible to utilize this withing the aggregate root to select the page of children results?

Something along these lines:

```
public class Parent{
int Id;
IList<Child> Children;
}


public Parent GetWithPagedChildren(int id, int page, int pageSize, out int count)
{
    //Query

    return Parentresult; //With one page of children populated.
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Actually, the eagerly loading requirement is not so important.  I just want the paged subset of the child objects loaded when I access them.

Comment: Why do you want to page the children? Are they too many to fit into memory?

Comment: @Stefan: It just seems wrong and wasteful to fetch the whole child collection from the DB when I know only a small subset is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't page and join-fetch child collections in the same query. But you can:

- Use a query to get the (paged) parents and one to load all the collections for those parents (read http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/01/16/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate.aspx for some concepts)
- Set `batch-size` on the collections to your page size. This will accomplish more or less the same, but automatically. There's even a patch that allows changing this dynamically: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2316

**Update** (for the new requirements):

As you've read, you can use `session.CreateFilter` to filter/sort/page a child collection. This works and it is supported everywhere.

Additionally, there's a patch ([NH-2319](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2319); I will convert to an addin, as it's unlikely to be accepted in the trunk) that allows using Linq for that. It's limited to some collection types and requires the relationship to be bidirectional, but allows the following:

```
var parent = GetParent();
var secondPageOfChildrenByName = parent.Children.AsQueryable()
                                                .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
                                                .Skip(PageSize * 1)
                                                .Take(PageSize)
                                                .ToList();
```

Comment: It's a pity, this must be a very common scenario.  Especially when sticking to DDD rules and only accessing objects via aggregate root traversal (I could build a child repository, but this means a repository for every entity, rather than just the aggregate roots.)  The fist example is not going to help I don't think.  Is the second option only available in v3? I'm using v2.2. unfortuantely.

Comment: The second option is available in 2.x, that's what I'm using right now, and is consistent with DDD.

Comment: Ok thanks. I read this (slightly old) post by ayende on this (http://ayende.com/Blog/2006/09/16/BatchingSupportInNHibernate.aspx) - he states that this is only supported for MSSQL. Do you know if this has changed?

Comment: That is about batch *updates*, not fetching, and it works with MSSQL and Oracle. Batch fetching works will all DBs.

Comment: Those updates look great - thanks Diego.  I seem to have missed the end of the bounty I added though - apologies for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just read this bit in the [NHibernate Documentation 'Querying tips and tricks' section (13.13)](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql-tipstricks):

```
//Collections are pageable by using the IQuery interface with a filter:

IQuery q = s.CreateFilter( collection, "" ); // the trivial filter
q.setMaxResults(PageSize);
q.setFirstResult(PageSize * pageNumber);
IList page = q.List();
```

I'm not entirely sure yet how this will work with a child collection but will try it and update this answer.